# Comparing aws [Athena,S3, Lambda ...] VS Hortonwork [HDFS, Hive, Oozie ...]

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using 'plain' Hadoop cluster Hortonworks with components HDFS, Hive, Oozie... vs some services on AWS like S3/Athena/Lambda?

my scenario data flow:
source data come from iot sensors in order to analytics and sometimes I need to query by deviceid & datetime with Hive/Athena ... (all conditions have been partitioned)

[image: compare image]

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantages of installing Hadoop yourself in any cloud provider is obviously cost and a little bit of maintenance.

For example, HDFS disk gets full, add more volumes. You need to upgrade and patch software yourself. You're charged every machine hour, for every machine and turning off just the namenode of the cluster will render it unusable for a period of time; if you do not have any business use-case for running the cluster overnight, you're wasting money

---

Therefore the advantage of storing data in cloud is.

1. While slower than HDFS, object store in S3 is significantly cheaper and scalable
2. Triggering actions via Lambda or another scheduler, can actually happen faster than Oozie launching a YARN job. Your code isn't tied to Hadoop, either, so your functions should be able to be smaller, although you may be limited in language options. If you combine lambda or other filesystem triggers with container schedulers like Kubernetes, you can open lots of options.
3. Querying your data any time you want with tools like AWS Glue and Athena, decouples the maintenance of a Hive metastore and a compatible query engine, whether that's Hive, Presto, Impala, Drill, etc. Anyone with AWS access can run an Athena query without needing to know an address of your HiveServer and how to appropriately connect to it (for example, you should secure it and make it highly available)